# Как создать динамические url?

Tags: веб-программирование, java-ee

Как создать ссылку типа этого: "https://kinogo.by/28327-love-and-monsters_2020.html"?
Не думаю, что они создают отдельную страницу для каждого фильма.

Comment: Java EE - стандарт широкий, как и спектр применяемых версий. О чём именно разговор? Сервлеты? JSF? MVC? RS? MicroProfile?

Comment: Речь идет о сервлетах

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6678490/8343843